# I get an UCSS error report on Quick.Cloud that takes up recourses. How to fix?

Tags: css

I'm using Quick.Cloud through Litespeed Server. I run a Wordpress page.
I see that I get this error, and it takes up CPU on the CDN server and eats up my quota.
It looks like this error is on every page. Below is just an example.

I have scanned through my CSS and I can't find any "background-color:#00000000 !important"
I have used search and find, but I can not find it. I've searched for the whole block, down to only #00000000. The latter was found on one place, but without !important.

[UCSS] https://pellvac.com/produkt-tagg/asksug-for-sot-och-aska
/* [ERROR] Unclosed block ( {background-color:#00000000 !important}@ ) : Please fix this css error a...

How do I find this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the CSS in an internal file made by the plugin "simple custom CSS and js" but I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
.woocommerce-cart .header-top {
    background-color: #00000000 !important;
}
```

However, I run the whole CSS document through a CSS validator. I found a missing } at the end of the document that I've added. It was not related to the CSS mentioned in the error message at all. I do not know if this was the solution to the error, but if it was I suppose I'll know in the next month when my credits are full again.  (it costs credits to run the UCSS, and this error appears to have eaten away on the free quota)